# How can I filter out a List from a .txt file using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am taking a Python class and I can't figure out a take home quiz. I am using IDLE to write the code.

We have to load a file called names.txt into a list. The file contains the following:

```
Joe Smith
000000
Jeff Mitchell
xxxxxxx
Benjamin Grant
12346
```

I need to filter out lines that contain the "xxxxxxx" or numbers. I am attempting to use list comprehension with the following code:

```
> names = open(r'C:\Users\abcdse\Documents\Python\names1.txt','r')
> names_contents = names.read()
> filtered_names = [n for n in names_contents if n !='xxxxxxx']
> names.close()
> print(filtered_names)
```

However, when I print the filtered_names output, names are not being filtered and rather than appearing in a dropdown format, they appear like this:

['J', 'o', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'm', 'i', 't', 'h', '\n', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\n', 'J', 'e', 'f', 'f', ' ', 'M', 'i', 't', 'c', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\n', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '\n', 'B', 'e', 'n', 'j', 'a', 'm', 'i', 'n', ' ', 'G', 'r', 'a', 'n', 't', '\n', '1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '\n']

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to filter out both, the "xxxxxxx" and numbers?

Thank you for your support as I get started with code.

Comment: You need to open the file and read it line by line. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: @Erick Esquivel if one of the answer below satisfies your question please accept it, so this question can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

```
names = open(r'C:\Users\abcdsed\Documents\Python\names1.txt','r')
name_contents = names.readlines()  # list of lines
filtered_names = [n for n in name_contents if (not n.isnumeric() or n != 'xxxxxxx']
```

Might want to look things up using your favorite search engine before posting here though. This is a very trivial question.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. 

Still wrapping my head around where to find the best resources and  was having a hard time finding something helpful on Google.

I would love to hear any tips on how to better utilize this forum.

Comment: E.g. I looked up "python reading a file line by line" and the first few results all introduce the reader to ```readlines()```. In my experience, simple search queries with fewer keywords work better than more verbose ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readlines` to read the data and list comprehension to filter out `xxx`

```
ss = '''
Joe Smith
000000
Jeff Mitchell
xxxxxxx
Benjamin Grant
12346
'''.strip()

with open('names.txt','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write data file

###############################


with open('names.txt') as f:
   lns = f.readlines()
   xx = [ln.strip() for ln in lns if ln.strip() != 'xxxxxxx']
   
print('\n'.join(xx))
```

Output

```
Joe Smith
000000
Jeff Mitchell
Benjamin Grant
12346
```

Answer (score 2):

`names_contents` is a string, so you are comparing a string against char in this line of code `n !='xxxxxxx'`. So first you have to split the string into list of strings representing each line. Try this

```
lines = names_contents.split("\n")
filtered_names = [n for n in lines if n !='xxxxxxx']
```

Answer (score 1):

The values you want to remove
`filter_vals = 'xxxxxxx\n'`

Read the file

```
with open('64797525.txt') as f:
    out = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines() if i not in filter_vals] # remove what's in the list
```

```
print(out)
['Joe Smith', '000000', 'Jeff Mitchell', 'Benjamin Grant', '12346']
```